# What is the proof to show that $3^n$ divides $(3n)!$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Working on a number theory question and I am quite stuck. How would you prove that $(3n)!/3^n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{N}$ being the natural numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof that $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$ is integer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164611/proof-that-frac2n2n-is-integer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: How many multiples of $3$ are there in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,3n\}$?

Comment: I mean technically, there'd be infinitely many multiples of 3. I guess I'm still a little confused.

Comment: @Azovax: There are infinitely many multiples of $3$ in the set $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}\;?$$ That’s what you’re telling me in the particular case that $n=4$.

Comment: Well I take that back. I suppose for the set ${1,2,....,3n}$ there's $n$ multiples of 3.

Comment: @Azovax: That’s right. And how many factors of $3$ are there in the denominator that need to be concelled in order to get an integer quotient?

Comment: I want to say 3n. That's an educated guess. I just tried the first three cases of $3^n$, and found 1,3,9

Comment: @Azovax: Whoa! The denominator is $3^n$; that’s $$\underbrace{3\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot 3}_{n\text{ factors}}\;.$$

Comment: Sorry, the first should be $3^n$ not $3n$. Still don't see a tie in to a proof.

Comment: @Azovax: It’s neither $3n$ nor $3^n$. You have $n$ factors of $3$ in the denominator. In order for the quotient to be an integer, you need to find $n$ factors of $3$ in the numerator. For example: $$\frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot \color{red}{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \color{red}{6} \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot \color{red}{9} \cdot 10 \cdot 11 \cdot\color{red}{12}}{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3}$$

Comment: So for each additional n, we are adding a three to the denominator and a multiple of three to the numerator. Makes sense. This "cancels" the denominator out, leaving a 1, and always having a natural number. I just can't form a technical explanation to it.

Comment: @Azovax: Right, that’s the idea. You could explain that $(3n)!$ is the product of the integers from $1$ through $3n$, which can be split into $M=\{3k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$, the multiples of $3$, and the set $S$ of all of the other factors. If $s$ is the product of the numbers in $S$, and $m$ is the product of the numbers in $M$, then $(3n)!=ms$. If you can now write $m=\text{something}\cdot 3^n$, you’ll be in business: you’ll have $(3n)!=3^n(\text{something}\cdot s)$, which is clearly a multiple of $3^n$. Can you work out what $\text{something}$ has to be?

Comment: Struggling to find something. I am really missing out on some middle step.

Comment: @Azovax: Try a small example: with $n=5$ you get $$m=3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12\cdot15=(3\cdot1)(3\cdot2)(3\cdot3)(3\cdot4)(3\cdot)=3^5\cdot5\text{ what ?}$$

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid. I can find that $3^5 \times 120=m$ but i don't know what that 120 is. Gahhhhh

Comment: @Azovax: It’s $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5$; what’s another name for that? (You’re getting there.)

Comment: So $m=3^n \times n!$

Comment: @Azovax: Yes!!!

Comment: So, to sum it up. $3n!=3^n \times (n! \times s)$ And when we plug this into our original problem, we get $(3^n \times (n! \times s)) / 3^n$ which is just $n! \times s$, which is a natural number.

Comment: @Azovax: You’ve got it; that’s exactly right.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.

Comment: @Azovax: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The largest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is the (finite) sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor{n\over p^k}\right\rfloor$$