# Prove that $p^n \nmid ((p - 1)n!)$ for all primes $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $p^n \nmid ((p - 1)n!)$ for all primes $p$ .

First I am thinking maybe modular arithmetic will help (although I am not sure) , and I don't know a quick and a general proof of this . Can anyone help ?

Comment: I think the question should be: "Prove that $p^n\nmid \big((p-1)n\big)!$."  The problem as stated seems quite weak.

Comment: That can be a possibility , but the question is actually what I have wrote .

Comment: My reason for doubting is: since $\gcd(p,p-1)=1$, the claim is equivalent to $p^n\nmid n!$.   This is true, but very weak.

Comment: For $p=2$ and $2^n$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808670/prove-that-2n-does-not-divide-n). Generalize it to $p$ and $p^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well-known that the maximal $k$ with $p^k\mid m!$ is given by
$$ k=\left\lfloor\frac mp\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac m{p^2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac m{p^3}\right\rfloor+\cdots<\frac mp+\frac m{p^2}+\frac m{p^3}+\cdots=\frac m{p-1}$$
When $m=(p-1)n$, this implies $k<n$, as desired.