# Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of size $n$ from the set $\{1, 2, ..., 2n\}$.

Tags: combinatorics

If $n$ must be greater than or equal to 2, prove that the cardinality of $S$ is a composite number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I see now that this is more simply a matter of proving that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is always composite. This is explained extremely clearly in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-2n-n2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer/).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-2n-n2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer

Comment: Can you show that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is always even?

Comment: I can indeed. :) The question @David Peterson linked to is excellent and gives some very clear examples as to how to solve this. Given that such an excellent explanation exists, I feel it would be best to mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{2n}{n} = \binom{2n-1}{n} +\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ and $\binom{2n-1}{n} = \binom{2n-1}{n-1}$, so $\binom{2n}{n}$ is even