# How to prove this using combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How do you proceed if you are required to prove for any natural number $n$ that $$\frac{n^2!}{(n!)^n}$$ is an integer. Here the ! sign represents factorial. I got absolutely no leads on this problem. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic? It suffices to show that for each prime the power occurring in $n^2!$ is higher than the one in $(n!)^n$.

Comment: Note that some of your Readers overlooked or ignored the request mentioned only in the *title* for proof by combinatorial methods.  It a good idea to include such requirements in the *body* of the Question as well.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I tried to come up with a proof based on your suggestion, even though it wouldn't be a good answer (not combinatorics). It turned out to be harder than I expected to put a bound on the highest power of a prime factor! I ended up with an unproven conjecture that the product of any $x$ consecutive counting numbers is divisible by each of $\{1,\ldots,x\}$ (or by $x!$, equivalently) and got stuck there...

Comment: I had indeed overlooked the request to use combinatorial methods because it was hidden in the title. @TimPederick, the arithmetic proof indeed seems to require something like your conjecture: Take any prime $p$. If its multiples occur $k$ times in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ (counting squares as two occurrences etc.), then they also occur at least $k$ times in $\{a+1,\dots,a+n\}$ for any $a\geq0$. Therefore $(a+1)\cdots(a+n)/n!$ is an integer for all $a\geq0$. Let $a$ range in $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and take the product of these integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is even if $n$ is a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-frac2nn2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer)

Comment: why are you flagging 3 year old questions with accepted answers, though?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We'll show that the above number is the size of a set with integer number of elements.

Assume we have $n$ types of balls, and from each type we have $n$ balls.
Obviously, there are $n^2$ balls. Let's set them up in a line; obviously, there is an **integer** number of ways to do that.

First we set them all in a line as they are different- permutation over $n^2$ different elements is defined as $n^2!$, now divide by number of substitutions for each type - $n!$ for each type we get just what we wanted:
$$\frac{n^2!}{(n!)^n} $$

Comment: I didn't know that. Very interesting, please tell me more

Answer (score 14):

How many ways are there to order a "word" made with $n$ letters, each of which occur $n$ times?

Answer (score 1):

The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$:
$$
(m+1)(m+2)\cdots(m+n)=\binom{m+n}{n}n!
$$

$n^2!$ is a product of $n$ products of $n$ consecutive integers:
$$
[1 \cdot 2 \cdots n]\dot[(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)]]\cdots
$$

Explicily,
$$
n^2! = \binom{n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}\cdots \binom{n^2}{n}(n!)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

a useful principle is that for any natural numbers $m,n$ we have:
$$
F_{n,0} | F_{n,m}
$$
where
$$
F(n,m) =  \prod_{j=1+m}^{n+m} j
$$
with this notation we have $F(n,0) = n!$ and
$$
(kn)! = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} F(n,kn)
$$
setting $k=n$ gives the required result