# Verify the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{(k!)^2((n-k)!)^2} = \dbinom{2n}{n}^2 $

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling to verify this identity. I've tried using the Principle of Mathematical Induction, combinatorial proofs, and a generalization of Vandermonde's Identity, all to no avail. It's the $(2n)!$ that's giving me problems.

Comment: I strongly advise you to look at this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983815/vandermond-identity-corollary-sum-v-0n-frac2nv2n-v2-2n-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a direct proof:**

Calculate the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{2n}$ and compare with the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n$.