# Does series with factorials converge/diverge: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n n!n!}{(2n)!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{4^n n!n!}\over{(2n)!}}$$

I tried the ratio test but got that the limit is equal to 1, this tells me nothing of whether the series diverges or converges. if I didn't make any errors when doing the ratio test,  it may diverge, but I need help proving that. Is there any other test I could try.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-2n-n2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer

Comment: the searched limit is infinity

Comment: See also [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\leq\sum_0^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=(1+1)^{2n}=4^n$$
So $$\frac{4^n n!n!}{(2n)!}\geq 1$$

Comment: Do you think  the series comparison test would help ?

Comment: It would, but it's not required. The terms of your series don't tend to $0$, so the series cannot be convergent.

Comment: how would you show that it diverges

Answer (score 1):

One approach is a comparison test, approximating the function using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). Since $n!= \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}\text{e}^{-n}(1+\mathcal{O}(\tfrac{1}{n}))$ we have $$\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)!}\approx\frac{4^{n}2\pi \cdot n^{2n+1}\text{e}^{-2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi} 2^{2n+1/2} n^{2n+1/2}\text{e}^{-2n}}=\sqrt{\pi n}.$$ The series therefore diverges.